# How to typeset right and left logical projection binary operations in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, logic

In his section on Boolean Basics in *The Art of Computer Programming* [Volume 4A](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/), Pre-Fascicle [0B](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc0b.pdf), Donald Knuth introduces notation for right and left logical projections, which appropriately look like the English letters `L` and `R` translated into logical connectives, found in Table 1 of page 3 (PDF page 7). This is precisely the notation I was looking for in [this StackExchange question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24180/concerning-the-logical-projection-how-to-express-nullary-and-unary-operations-a).

However, I'm not sure what command is used to output these symbols in LaTeX, and I can't located them in [the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List](http://get-software.net/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) either. Does anyone know how Donald Knuth came up with these symbols and how to typeset them in LaTeX?

Comment: Perhaps related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154149/identifying-mystery-r-symbol

Comment: do you mean this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154149/identifying-mystery-r-symbol?rq=1?

Comment: Yes! That's one of them. That's called the right logical projection. There's also one that looks like an `L`, the left logical projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending my first approach at [Identifying Mystery "R" Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154149/identifying-mystery-r-symbol), to include a `\KnL` of the same height and width as `\KnR`.  EDITED to tweak the quality of the symbols under large magnification.

Based on OP comments, EDITED to adjust size to the height of an "i" using `\scalerel*{item to scale}{item of target size}`; also enclosed the solution in a `\mathbin` to address spacing considerations.  Note that the target size can be changed by the user to something other than an "i", so as to suit their sensibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\KnRgap{\rule{1.63ex}{0ex}\rule[-.3ex]{0ex}{1.8ex}}
\def\KnR{\kern1pt\mathbin{\scalerel*{%
\stackinset{r}{0pt}{b}{0pt}{\rotatebox{53}{\rule{.07ex}{1.29ex}}}{%
\stackinset{l}{0pt}{t}{.02ex}{\rule{.07ex}{1.8ex}}{%
\stackinset{l}{.02ex}{t}{.02ex}{\rule{1ex}{.07ex}}{%
\stackinset{r}{0pt}{t}{.02ex}{\scalebox{.76}{$\supset\mkern -2mu$}}{%
\KnRgap%
}}}}}{i}}\kern1pt%
}
\def\KnL{\kern1pt\mathbin{\scalerel*{%
\stackinset{l}{0pt}{t}{.02ex}{\rule{.07ex}{1.78ex}}{%
\stackinset{l}{.02ex}{b}{0pt}{\rule{1.53ex}{.07ex}}{%
\KnRgap%
}}}{i}}\kern1pt%
}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{P} \KnR \mathcal{Q} $~~Right projection; second dictator%

$\mathcal{P} \KnL \mathcal{Q} $~~Left projection
\end{document}
```

[image]

One advantage of using the `\scalerel` approach is that it automatically accounts for the math style (shown here in `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`):

[image]

And extending the second approach (likewise EDITED to address the size issue) from that answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varcup}{3}{matha}{"59}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\KnRgap{\rule{1.45ex}{0ex}\rule[-.3ex]{0ex}{1.8ex}}
\def\KnR{\kern1pt\mathbin{\scalerel*{%
\stackinset{r}{0pt}{b}{0pt}{\rotatebox{45}{\rule{.08ex}{1.14ex}}}{%
\stackinset{l}{0pt}{t}{.02ex}{\rule{.08ex}{1.8ex}}{%
\stackinset{l}{.02ex}{t}{0.0pt}{\rule{.7ex}{.08ex}}{%
\stackinset{r}{0pt}{t}{0.0ex}{\scalebox{.81}{%
  \rotatebox{90}{$\varcup\mkern -2mu$}}}{%
\KnRgap%
}}}}}{i}}\kern1pt%
}
\def\KnL{\kern1pt\mathbin{\scalerel*{%
\stackinset{l}{0pt}{t}{.02ex}{\rule{.08ex}{1.78ex}}{%
\stackinset{l}{}{b}{}{\rule{1.4ex}{.08ex}}{%
{%
\KnRgap%
}}}}{i}}\kern1pt%
}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{P} \KnR \mathcal{Q} $~~Right projection; second dictator%

$\mathcal{P} \KnL \mathcal{Q} $~~Left projection
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Steven, thanks so much for this! However it might be displaying a little bit larger than intended (Knuth's were the same size as the other logical symbols `∨` and `∧`). What do you think? Here's an image of the output I'm getting: http://i.imgur.com/TIsJEOw.png

Comment: @EthanAlvaree I see your point.  When I addressed it in the other question, there was no issue of "proper size" to address.  Also, I'm guessing these should be surrounded with a `\mathbin{}` or `\mathrel{}`.  Perhaps when I get a moment, I will try to merely scale them slightly smaller and repost.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Please see revision.

Comment: It's perfect... Thank you Steven! Hopefully others searching for these symbols can find this StackExchange question and answer.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree You are most welcome.  Glad to help.  Best wishes.