# Undefined Control Sequence when using $\R$

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, sharelatex

Using the following packages;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsthm}     
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

It says undefined control sequence when writing

```
{It is called a simple arc of a curve, the set $C$ of points $M(x,y) \in \text{$\R$} ^2 $ 
(two-dimensional Euclidean space) satisfying the equation:}
```

also changing this to the following doesn't work

```
{It is called a simple arc of a curve, the set $C$ of points $M(x,y) \in \R ^2 $
```

I have included

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

like it says to do to fix the issue on most forums

Comment: And where is `\R` defined? Please, make complete small document that we can tested it. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Beside the point, but `\text{$\R$}` doesn't really make sense.  You're leaving math mode with `\text`, and then immediately going back into it with `$`.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154149/identifying-mystery-r-symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the excellent accepted answer: There are many alternatives to `amsfonts` for this symbol.

In the modern toolchain, there is no need to load any additional packages beyond `unicode-math` to get a ℝ that looks like the one from the early answer.  It is already set up by default.

However, you can load the double-struck alphabet from any math font, or any display font that you’d rather use, with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  For example, to use [Typoliner](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/typoliner):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=bb]{Typoliner-RW-Light.ttf}

\newcommand\setR{\symbb{R}}

\begin{document}
Let \(S \subset \setR\).
\end{document}
```

[image: Typoliner sample]

If you need compatibility with PDFLaTeX, or you would rather use a legacy NFSS font, you might want to use [the `mathalfa` package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf) to select your supplemental math alphabets.

Answer (score 7):

`\R` is not a standard LaTeX command and is not defined by any of the packages you load. It's a custom command that a lot of people seem to like, but you have to define it yourself. Presumably you want something like

```
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
```

Although I myself recommend against it. The reasons are subtle. There's nothing to stop you defining one letter commands like `\R` and, as many discussions on this site have concluded, `\R` is not inherently any more or less dangerous than `\realnumbers`, however a lot of people land themselves in trouble because they don't realise that *a lot* of one letter commands are already defined by LaTeX. They then define over them and get weird errors that cause a lot more problems than they're worth. `\R` is also pretty syntactically meaningless. Myself, if I had to do this, I would go with `\reals` instead, I think, but this is really none of my business, it's up to you what shortcuts you wish to define, if, indeed, you wish to define them.

Anyway, you will need the `amssymb` package for this to work, or `amsfonts`, since they define `\mathbb{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

It is called a simple arc of a curve, the set $C$ of points
$M(x,y) \in \R^{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In other news, I'm not quite sure why you seem to have braces around your sentence, in general they would not be needed so I've removed them here.

Comment: Many people use double letters for this reason, like `\RR`, `\CC`, &c. And some purists prefer to define them as `\mathbf{R}`, `\mathbf{C}`,…